# styling html table in external css doesn't work

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a jsp file that holds html elements, it has a table in it with a specific id. When I add the border: 1px; styling internally then it works, but when I want to use a css file that specifies styling, then it doesn't, there's no border at all as a result.

the relevant part of the jsp file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Airline Database</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/PassengerStyle.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="main" width="1300px">
             ...
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

the PassengerStyle.css file:

```
#main {
     border: 1px solid black;
}
```

the css file is in the styles folder that is in the same folder as the jsp file.

What did I miss?

Comment: is the network tab of firebug showing errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably can't find the stylesheet, i.e. the url is wrong. Have you tried navigating to where the code in 'view source' thinks the file is located? That's probably different then where it is.

You can also try adding body { background-color: red; } to see if any styles from that stylesheet apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebug or Chrome developer tools to see if your CSS is being overridden by different rule, and you can use the network tab of those tools to see if there were any errors loading the external stylesheet.

Adding `!important` to your css style can help in debugging, although I don't recommend it for production use.

Also try clearing your cache to see if a previous version of the stylesheet is being used.

Comment: the problem wasn't that it took a different rule, it was trying a wrong url, but using the chrome developer tools was a good idea, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to see if any other styles from the stylesheet apply (or do a test), if they do, then I would wonder is the table dynamically generated? If other styles do work, I would try giving the table to be styled a class in the tag versus using the id reference in the style sheet and see if that works. If nothing applies, probably a broken style sheet link.

I would also recommend putting the 'width=1300px' in the css style sheet along with the other css styles.

Comment: it is dynamically generated, i've put the width in the css, but the problem was that it was trying to reach on the wrong url

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#main {
     border: 1px solid black !important;
}
```